# Page not found (404) No Profile matches the given query. using django multi tenants

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am encountering a 404 error with the message "No Profile matches the given query" when trying to access the crm_details view with profile IDs higher than 4 in a multi-tenancy Django application

views.py
def crm_details(request, profile_id):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
tenant = Tenant.objects.get(schema_name=request.tenant)  # Fetch the current tenant
profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, id=profile_id, tenant=tenant)  # Filter by tenant
crm_instance = crm.objects.filter(person_detail=profile, tenant=tenant).first()  # Filter by tenant
properties = AddProperty.objects.filter(tenant=tenant)

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = crmForm(request.POST, instance=crm_instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            crm_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            crm_entry.person_detail = profile
            crm_entry.save()

    else:
        form = crmForm(instance=crm_instance)

    context = {
        'profile': profile,
        'crm_form': form,
        'properties': properties
        
    }

    return render(request, 'crm_details.html', context)

return redirect("blog:user_login")
```

def create_profile(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
tenant = Tenant.objects.get(schema_name=request.tenant)  # Fetch the current tenant
if request.method == 'POST':
form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
profile = form.save(commit=False)
profile.tenant = tenant  # Associate the profile with the current tenant
profile.save()
return redirect('blog:profile_list')
else:
form = ProfileForm()

```
    return render(request, 'create_profile.html', {'form': form})
return redirect("blog:user_login")
```

def add_property(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
tenant = Tenant.objects.get(schema_name=request.tenant)  # Fetch the current tenant
if request.method == 'POST':
form = AddPropertyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
property_instance = form.save(commit=False)
property_instance.tenant = tenant  # Associate the property with the current tenant
property_instance.created_by = request.user
property_instance.save()
return redirect('blog:property_list')
else:
form = AddPropertyForm()
else:
return redirect('user_login')

```
return render(request, 'add_property.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).